# touchesEnded not called

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have one custom table name tbltask in my view and on touch begin and on touch moved method i am creating a lable dynamically.

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];



     self.scrollEnabled=NO;
    CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:[self superview]]; 
    CGPoint pointtask=[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointtask];
    rowid=indexPath.row;




      app.sublable=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((point.x)-145, (point.y)-50, 300, 40)];
    app.sublable.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentRight;
    messagedrag=[app.arraddtask objectAtIndex:rowid];
    app.sublable.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",messagedrag.msgsubject];
    app.sublable.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"black.png"]];  

    app.sublable.layer.cornerRadius=8.0;
      app.sublable.layer.borderWidth=4;
     app.sublable.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
       app.sublable.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

    UIFont *f = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:16];
    app.sublable.font = f;
    [app.sublable setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];

    [self.superview addSubview:app.sublable];



}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    if(app.sublable!=nil)
    {

        [app.sublable removeFromSuperview];

    }
    CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:[self superview]]; 
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];

    NSLog(@"............super %f",[self superview].frame.origin.y);

    app.sublable=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((point.x)-145, (point.y)-50, 300, 40)];
    app.sublable.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentRight;
    messagedrag=[app.arraddtask objectAtIndex:rowid];
    app.sublable.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",messagedrag.msgsubject];

     app.sublable.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"black.png"]];  

    app.sublable.layer.borderWidth=4;
    app.sublable.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
    app.sublable.layer.cornerRadius=8.0;
    app.sublable.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
       UIFont *f = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:16];
    app.sublable.font = f;
    [app.sublable setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];

    [self.superview addSubview:app.sublable];






}
```

it result in that.
[image]

so when i touch on tbltask touchBegan method start working and create one lable with subject is written on that in superview which is main view here on where the tbltask is there as you can see.(the bottom one is table task)
Now when i call  touchesEnded method ::

```
 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
    {
        //<my stuff>

        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
        NSString *taskname=[[NSString alloc] init];
         self.scrollEnabled=YES;
        if(app.sublable!=nil)
        {
           taskname=app.sublable.text;
            [app.sublable removeFromSuperview];
        }

        [taskdelegate droptask:self strtask:taskname];


    }
```

this subject is dropped on above table.
[image]

It works fine.but when i touch the tbltask left to right or right to left something is happened and touch end method is not called so sublable is not removed from the view like this.like this...[image]

so what am i doing wrong in this...
and yes i m calling the touch events on table touch as you will notice.
please help me in this problem...
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `touchesBegan`, etc will not be called for `UITableView` because it overrides them already. To get touches, you'll have to override `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: but it work fine on tableview... the problem is only when i touch from  left to right or right to left... as i say....

Comment: i thought that when i touch in that way didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called in between touch move method so i also checked it by putting the break point on didSelectRowAtIndexPath method but flow doesnt go in that method.

Comment: Your problem is that UIGestureRecognizer is recognizing a swipe, which overrides touchesEnded.